# Filter results based on From & To Date not working if we remove HH ; mm : sec

Tags: date

we are Displaying From & To Date for filtering orders based on those dates.

here 00:0:00 & 23:59:59 is displaying along with from & To date. [ hours : min : sec]

[image]

but i want to hide : **00:00:00 & 23:59:59** , so i removed those text from code, after that Filtering based on Dates not working.

[image]

```
if (isset($_POST['post_at']) && $_POST['post_at'] != '')
    {
    $orderFromDate = $_POST['post_at'] . " 00:0:00";
    }
  else
    {
    $orderFromDate = '';
    }

if (isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && $_POST['post_at_to_date'] != '')
    {
    $orderToDate = $_POST['post_at_to_date'] . " 23:59:59";
    }
  else
    {
    $orderToDate = '';
    }

function getDesignerCollection()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['post_at']) && $_POST['post_at'] != '')
        {
        $orderFromDate = $_POST['post_at'] . "00:0:00 ";
        }
      else
        {
        $orderFromDate = '';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && $_POST['post_at_to_date'] != '')
        {
        $orderToDate = $_POST['post_at_to_date'] . "23:59:59 ";
        }
      else
        {
        $orderToDate = '';
        }

        if ($orderFromDate != '') $order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
            'gteq' => $orderFromDate
        ));
        if ($orderToDate != '') $order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
            'lteq' => $orderToDate
        ));

        foreach($order as $orderData)
        {
        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");
        }

    }
```

**script**

```
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "button",
buttonText: "Date Picker",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
});
$(function() {
$("#post_at").datepicker();
$("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
});
```

**Edit**

We have below code in form, where **value** of below textfield is reason for displaying **hh:mm:ss**.

```
<input  id="post_at" 

value="<?php

if ($orderFromDate != '')
    {
    echo $orderFromDate;
    } ?>" name="post_at"  />
```

i tried below code to remove hh:mm:ss , but still its not working.

```
<input  id="post_at" value="<?php

if ($orderFromDate != '')
    {

    $newPostStartDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($orderFromDate));
    echo $newPostStartDate;
    }   ?>" name="post_at"  />
```

Comment: Your filter function expects date to be in that format _YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00_ but jquery sends only as 'yy-mm-dd' you need to smooth out the difference in your controller.And 00:0:00 is invalid

Comment: @Novice  i replaced to `00:00:00`, also changed jquery code to `yy-mm-dd` did't worked, can you please what code i need to replace in php code ?

Comment: i would love to help but i don't know what format does your filtering function expects (see the `$order->addFieldToFilter`) Looking that i'd guess you are using Magento but unfortunately i no nothing technical about it so i'd suggest go over http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for support @Novice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will check to see if `$orderFromDate` contains a valid date/time value (determined by the previous checks on the `$_POST['post_at']` value), and use that information to set the current value for the HTML input of the same name.

```
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="From Date"
    id="post_at"
    value="<?php echo 
                $orderFromDate != '' ?
                date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['post_at']))
                : '';
           ?>"
    name="post_at"
/>
```

*The above example uses shorthand php to simplify the condition. (Line breaks added to reduce scrolling in this example)*

Comment: please [edit] your answer to provide sufficient explanation. Code-only answers are frowned upon for a reason.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I edited the solution to provide a better explanation and minimized the condition to shorthand which imo is better for inline checks.